# Странное поведение примера из официальной документации

Tags: javascript, c#, anglesharp

Начил читать официальную дукументацию по anglesharp,последний пример работает как то странно [Events in JavaScript and C#](https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Examples.html).По логике должен получить текст  из событый **load** и **hello** из скрипта а получаю только из с# кода.

**Код**

```
using AngleSharp;
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public async static void EventScriptingExample()
        {
            //We require a custom configuration
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithJs();

            //Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the given config
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

            //This is our sample source, we will trigger the load event
            var source = @"<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head><title>Event sample</title></head>
        <body>
        <script>
        console.log('Before setting the handler!');

        document.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log('Document loaded!');
        });

        document.addEventListener('hello', function() {
        console.log('hello world from JavaScript!');
        });

        console.log('After setting the handler!');
        </script>
        </body>";

            var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(source));

            //HTML should be output in the end
            Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);

            //Register Hello event listener from C# (we also have one in JS)
            document.AddEventListener("hello", (s, ev) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hello world from C#!");
            });

            var e = document.CreateEvent("event");
            e.Init("hello", false, false);
            document.Dispatch(e);
        }


        static void Main()
        {

            EventScriptingExample();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

**Как должно быть:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что получаю:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Note:** То есть событие выполняется только из с# кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное пример просто не полный. У меня заработало вот так:

```cs
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Js;
```

```cs
class ConsoleLogger : IConsoleLogger
{
    public void Log(object[] values)
    {
        foreach (object value in values)
            Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public async static Task EventScriptingExample()
    {
        //We require a custom configuration
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithJs().WithConsoleLogger(c => new ConsoleLogger());

        //Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the given config
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

        //This is our sample source, we will trigger the load event
        var source = @"<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head><title>Event sample</title></head>
    <body>
    <script>
    console.log('Before setting the handler!');

    document.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('Document loaded!');
    });

    document.addEventListener('hello', function() {
    console.log('hello world from JavaScript!');
    });

    console.log('After setting the handler!');
    </script>
    </body>";

        var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(source));

        //HTML should be output in the end
        Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);

        //Register Hello event listener from C# (we also have one in JS)
        document.AddEventListener("hello", (s, ev) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world from C#!");
        });

        var e = document.CreateEvent("event");
        e.Init("hello", false, false);
        document.Dispatch(e);
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        await EventScriptingExample();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Я поправил еще асинхронность, чтобы все красиво было.

```
Before setting the handler!
After setting the handler!
Document loaded!
<html><head><title>Event sample</title></head>
    <body>
    <script>
    console.log('Before setting the handler!');

    document.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('Document loaded!');
    });

    document.addEventListener('hello', function() {
    console.log('hello world from JavaScript!');
    });

    console.log('After setting the handler!');
    </script>
    </body></html>
hello world from JavaScript!
hello world from C#!
```

Comment: Cпасибо вам,'WithConsoleLogger'-что делает? Можно как-то убрать сам документ из вывода в поток(на консоль) оставить только  текст выполных операторов в js?

Comment: Ответ на мой 1 вопрос: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Js

Comment: @Vladimir `Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);` ни о чем вам не говорит разве? Закомментируйте эту строчку и посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: извините не заметил